# How to iterate a list accessing two indexes at a time and moving one index time after each iteration?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list like this:

```
a_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

How do I iterate over it to produce the output below?

```
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
5,6
...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a zip with an offset on the start and stop:

```
print(list(zip(a_list[:-1], a_list[1:])))
```

Slightly more flexible solution that doesn't rely on list syntax.

```
def special_read(data):
    last = None
    for curr in data:
        if last is not None:
            yield last, curr
        last = curr

...

for a, b in special_read(a_list):
    print(a, b)
```

To make this work for variable sized windows, you could use a deque. This acts as ring buffer, overwriting itself as it exceeds the window size:

```
import collections

def window(data, size=2):
    queue = collections.deque(maxlen=size)
    for i in data:
        queue.append(i)
        if len(queue) == size:
            yield (*queue,)

for w in window([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], size=3):
    print(w)
```

```
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 5)
(4, 5, 6)
(5, 6, 7)
(6, 7, 8)
```

Comment: `[:-1]` is not needed, zip will only use shortest input

Comment: @flakes Thanks! I made a made an attempt in my answer just using the basic python stuff. Could you check its robustness?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (it will handle *uneven* lists):

```py
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for i in range(0, len(a_list), 2):
    print(a_list[i], "" if i + 1 == len(a_list) else a_list[i + 1], sep=",")
```

Prints:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
```

---

For `a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` it will print:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
9,
```

Comment: Could you check out the solution I made? Not sure if it's good or not.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing I made a similar attempt at this problem:

```
a_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a_count = 0

for i in a_list:
    if a_count == len(a_list) - 1:
        break
    else:
        print(a_list[a_count],',', a_list[a_count+1]) 
        a_count+=1
```